# Can the following integral be computed efficiently without knowing that $\int {\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx}=\arctan(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Compute $\displaystyle \int{\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}}$.

My first thought was to use long division which resulted in $\int {1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx}$. However I then did not come any further. The solution did the same thing and just stated that the integral obtained after long division is an elementary integral and $\int {1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx} =x-\arctan(x)+C$ with $x\in\mathbb R$. So did I just struggle because I didn't know that $\int {\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx}=\arctan(x)$ - or should I have been able to come up with that solution (in an efficient way) without knowing this?

Comment: The usual method is trig substitution.

Comment: Isn't $\int {\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx}=\arctan(x)$ a trig substitution?

Comment: Well, the general rule is: you can't evaluate quite a few integrals with elementary functions. If you don't know some elementary integrals like this one, you can't integrate almost anything.

Comment: @ProfessorVector So the answer is yes, one needs to know that $\int {\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx}=\arctan(x)$? Even if this integral may be computed in another way, knowing that $\int {\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx}=\arctan(x)$ is necessary to know for many other integrals, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @timtam No, a trig substitution is a u-substitution method with trig functions.  In this case  you can recognize that $x^2 + 1$ looks a bit like $\tan^2(\theta) +1$ which simplifies to $\sec^2(\theta)$.  So you try the substitution $x = \tan(\theta)$ and see where it takes you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=\frac{1+x^2-1}{1+x^2}=1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-\frac{1}{(x+i)(x-i)}$$
$$y=1-\frac{i}{2 (x+i)}+\frac{i}{2 (x-i)}$$ Just finish